# Is there a categorization of Disney "classic" live-action movies similar to for animated movies?

Tags: disney

For Disney animated movies, there is a subset of so-called "Disney Classics". These distinguish the really well-known/acclaimed films such as "*The Lion King*", "*Snow White*", "*Aladdin*", "*Bambi*" et al, from rather more low-budget or less well-known films such as "*The Brave Little Toaster*", "*Teacher's Pet*", "*Mickey, Donald, Goofy: The Three Musketeers*" and so on. For example, typically Disney theme park rides will be adaptations of the "classic" movies as opposed to others.

For live-action films a similar line can be drawn: one has the classic films like "*Treasure Island*", "*Swiss Family Robinson*", "*Pollyanna*", and so on; however there are also a huge number of films that practically no-one will ever have heard of, such as "*The Light In The Forest*", "*Tonka*",  "*Superdad*" and many more.

Is there a distinction that can be made in order to isolate that group of Disney live-action films which are perhaps part of common parlance when referring to "Disney movies"?

Comment: If disney made the movie, it's a *Disney Movie*

Answer (score 2):

The term for the Disney animated movie is *Disney animated features*

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Disney_theatrical_animated_features

They used to actually use the number in their marketing material (i.e., *"Walt Disney presents their 28th animated feature, The Little Mermaid"*)

As for live action movie, there's no real formal distinction (since Disney movies now include the Marvel, Star Wars and Muppets movies) but in general if they released it in a theater with the term "Disney's" at the beginning (i.e., *"Disney's TRON"*, *"Disney's Treasure Island"*) you could draw a distinction between "Disney Movies" and, say, Kill Bill (done by Miramax who was owned by Disney at the time. Seriously.)

Comment: Kill Bill is Disney's? I mean Tarrantino's Kill Bill is Disney's? Wow!